# ie vs chrome window.location.href and <base> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, window.location

I have a problem with redirecting with javascript to a different page upon the click on a `<td>`.  For my websites I use the `<base href="">` tag as a starting point for my links.

So consider this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Login</title>
<base href="http://www.mysite.com/MyWebsite/manage/" />
```

special reference to `<base href="http://www.mysite.com/MyWebsite/manage/" />`

and consider this jQuery:

```
//Set row clicking
    $('table#alerts_table').on("click", "td", function () {
        var alert_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').val();
        var href = 'alerts/alert.php?id=' + alert_id;
        if (href) { window.location.href = href; }
    });
```

special reference to

```
var href = 'alerts/alert.php?id=' + alert_id;
if (href) { window.location.href = href; }
```

and consider that my current position on the website is already in the folder called alerts as follows:
http://www.mysite.com/MyWebsite/manage/**alerts**/index.php

I want to move from index.php to alert.php.

On chrome all works as expected i.e. the base href `http://www.mysite.com/MyWebsite/manage/` is concatenated to `alerts/alert.php?id=1` and I am redirected accordingly.

However in IE
the folder alerts is doubled: http://www.mysite.com/MyWebsite/manage/**alerts/alerts**/alert.php?id=1

This means that it is not taking the base URL from the base tag but it is using relative paths.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you may use:

```
   document.location.replace();
```

function. you will not reqire to use the base option. it will be redirected to page or subdirectory present in the same directory.